# How to count specific elements in an XML file using FLWOR?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery, flwor

I'm looking to count the sum of all tags `Order` in `Orders` for the sample `xml` below.  The total sum.

How can I return the number of element tags `foo`?  Here, a sort of count is:

```
1
1
```

whereas I'm looking for the sum only:  2.

query:

```
for $i in doc("foo.xml")/windward-studios/Orders/Order
return count($i)
```

[sample](https://gist.github.com/NICKSAUNDERS/2a1a9de15e2b52de6fd89642379d7342) xml:

```
<windward-studios>
  <Orders>
    <Order OrderID="10248">
      <CustomerID>VINET</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>5</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1996-07-04T14:25:55</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1996-08-01T06:43:44</RequiredDate>
      <ShippedDate>1996-07-16T04:00:12</ShippedDate>
      <ShipVia>3</ShipVia>
      <Freight>32.3800</Freight>
      <ShipName>Vins et alcools Chevalier</ShipName>
      <ShipAddress>59 rue de l'Abbaye</ShipAddress>
      <ShipCity>Reims</ShipCity>
      <ShipRegion/>
      <ShipPostalCode>51100</ShipPostalCode>
      <ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
      <OrderDetails>
        <OrderDetail>
          <ProductID>11</ProductID>
          <UnitPrice>14.0000</UnitPrice>
          <Quantity>12</Quantity>
          <Discount>0</Discount>
        </OrderDetail>
        <OrderDetail>
          <ProductID>42</ProductID>
          <UnitPrice>9.8000</UnitPrice>
          <Quantity>10</Quantity>
          <Discount>0</Discount>
        </OrderDetail>
        <OrderDetail>
          <ProductID>72</ProductID>
          <UnitPrice>34.8000</UnitPrice>
          <Quantity>5</Quantity>
          <Discount>0</Discount>
        </OrderDetail>
      </OrderDetails>
    </Order>
    <Order OrderID="10249">
      <CustomerID>TOMSP</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>6</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1996-07-05T06:39:18</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1996-08-16T03:39:38</RequiredDate>
      <ShippedDate>1996-07-10T14:39:39</ShippedDate>
      <ShipVia>1</ShipVia>
      <Freight>11.6100</Freight>
      <ShipName>Toms Spezialitäten</ShipName>
      <ShipAddress>Luisenstr. 48</ShipAddress>
      <ShipCity>Münster</ShipCity>
      <ShipRegion/>
      <ShipPostalCode>44087</ShipPostalCode>
      <ShipCountry>Germany</ShipCountry>
      <OrderDetails>
        <OrderDetail>
          <ProductID>14</ProductID>
          <UnitPrice>18.6000</UnitPrice>
          <Quantity>9</Quantity>
          <Discount>0</Discount>
        </OrderDetail>
        <OrderDetail>
          <ProductID>51</ProductID>
          <UnitPrice>42.4000</UnitPrice>
          <Quantity>40</Quantity>
          <Discount>0</Discount>
        </OrderDetail>
      </OrderDetails>
    </Order>
  </Orders>
</windward-studios>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were iterating over each of the `Order` elements and then asking for the count of each element.

Instead, ask for the count of the `Order` elements:

```
let $orders := doc("foo.xml")/windward-studios/Orders/Order
return count($orders)
```

You can do this more simply without a FLWOR:

```
count(doc("foo.xml")/windward-studios/Orders/Order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inviting comments on:

```
for $x at $i in db:open("southwind")/windward-studios/Orders/Order
return $i
```

which I find interesting because the index could possible be used as an attribute.  see:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xquery_select.asp